# Android: Urban Airship 6.0.1: android:elevation no resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

i'm trying to add Urban Airship Library to my project. I followed the steps exactly but when i build i get this error

```
No resource found that matches the given name: attr'android:elevation'


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- From: file:/Users/build/workspace/android-library/UrbanAirship/src/main/res/values-v21/styles.xml -->
    <eat-comment/>
    <style name="Widget.UrbanAirship.InAppMessage.Banner" parent="Base.Widget.UrbanAirship.InAppMessage.Banner">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ua_iam_background</item>
        <item name="android:elevation">@dimen/ua_iam_banner_elevation</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

This is my gradle file dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.0.0'
```

My targetSdkVersion is 21 and i also updated my APIs from the SDK manager

http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/android.html for reference

Please help me. Thanks!

**UPDATE 1: Android part in gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
        renderscriptTargetApi 22
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the android section of your build.gradle file?

Comment: @ralepinski I posted the android section

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting the compileSdkVersion to 21

Comment: Thanks, that has fixed it :)

Comment: Awesome! You might want to use 22 now that 5.1 is out and you are using the v22 version of the support libraries.